# Do lured Pokemon appear on sightings?

Tags: pokemon-go

When a lured Pokemon appears at a lure, will it appear on my sightings list if I am nearby?

Answer (score 3):

**No, they do not.**

Sometimes this is hard to tell, because there could be another of the same Pokemon nearby, so it shows in your list. However, I have definitely seen Pokemon at lured stops which were **not** in my sightings list as recently as last weekend.

Here are some other players who have reported the same thing:
[Reddit](https://m.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4wsrgx/pokemon_go_update_20160808/d69mf6n)
[Some crazy person that basically wrote a paper on using the sightings list](https://mewpro.cc/2016/07/30/how-to-use-nearby-to-find-pokemon/)

Comment: Agree, I saw this as recently as yesterday, in the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

**No. In addition, Pokémon that are spawning due to incense will no either.**

Side Note: Based on screenshots of the beta "Nearby" feature, it looks like Pokémon near Pokéstops will be listed as Nearby in the new system. I assume Lure Module spawned Pokémon will show up in this section, as well. For now, though, lure module Pokémon will not show up in Sightings.

Comment: I don't think this is true. I regularly see Pokemon at lured stops that don't show up in my sightings list.

Comment: Huh, I thought they did. I'm pretty sure they used to when it was the Nearby system. I'll update my answer.